# Unsupervised Classification: Assign classes to to data

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, unsupervised-learning, multilabel-classification

I have a set of data from a drill hole, it contains information about different geomechanical properties every 2 meters. I am trying to create geomechanical domains, and assign each point to a different domain.

I am trying to use random forest classification, and am unsure how to relate the proximty matrix (or any result from the randomForest function) to labels.

My humble code so far is as follows:

```
dh <- read.csv("gt_1_classification.csv", header = T)

#replace all N/A with 0
dh[is.na(dh)] <- 0
library(randomForest)
dh_rf <- randomForest(dh, importance=TRUE, proximity=FALSE, ntree=500, type=unsupervised, forest=NULL)
```

I would like the classifier to decide the domains on its own.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Might have been a useful question if there were enough data for testing of code and demonstration of results. As it is it seems too vague for further effort.

Comment: @42- the same challenge could be done with Iris dataset for example. If you remove the species column and try to write a classifier that would look at the data and assign species its self - same problem here.

Comment: A more appropriate response would be to present code that loads `iris` and performs the actions you imagine would construct an object for further analysis.

Comment: @CHopp Think about it like this - is it more reasonable for a person asking a question/favor to do the work of creating a reproducible example 1 time, or for everyone of the N people who might try to do him the favor of solving his problem do the work of setting up a reproducible example? This would mean that the work is done N times where N might be several to dozens or even hundreds. Both the philosophical and economic answers would clearly be that the requestor should do the work 1 time. Not to mention the MCVE rule on StackOverflow... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Anyway, Random Forest is supervised. So, what you'd have to do is to create your own labels with cluster analysis, or a heuristic, or something like that. Then train a RF on the created labels. See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72370/how-to-perform-unsupervised-random-forest-classification-using-breimans-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hack-R is correct -- first it is necessary to explore the data using some clustering (unsupervised learning) methods.  I've provided some sample code using the R built-in mtcars data as a demonstration:

```
# Info on the data
?mtcars
head(mtcars)
pairs(mtcars)    # Matrix plot

# Calculate the distance between each row (car with it's variables)
# by default, Euclidean distance = sqrt(sum((x_i - y_i)^2)
?dist
d <- dist(mtcars)
d # Potentially huge matrix

# Use the distance matrix for clustering
# First we'll try hierarchical clustering
?hclust
c <- hclust(d)
c

# Plot dendrogram of clusters
plot(c)

# We might want to try 3 clusters
# need to specify either k = # of groups
groups3 <- cutree(c, k = 3) # "g3" = "groups 3"
# cutree(hcmt, h = 230) will give same result
groups3
# Or we could do several groups at once
groupsmultiple <- cutree(c, k = 2:5)
head(groupsmultiple)

# Draw boxes around clusters
rect.hclust(c, k = 2, border = "gray")
rect.hclust(c, k = 3, border = "blue")
rect.hclust(c, k = 4, border = "green4")
rect.hclust(c, k = 5, border = "darkred")

# Alternatively we can try K-means clustering
# k-means clustering
?kmeans
km <- kmeans(mtcars, 5)
km

# Graph based on k-means
install.packages("cluster")
require(cluster)
clusplot(mtcars, # data frame
     km$cluster, # cluster data
     color = TRUE, # color
     lines = 3, # Lines connecting centroids
     labels = 2) # Labels clusters and cases
```

After running on your own data, consider which definition of clusters captures the level of similarity of interest to you.  You can then create a new variable with a "level" for each cluster and then create a supervised model to that.

Here's a decision tree example using the same mtcars data.  NOTE that here I used mpg as the response -- you would want to use your new variable based on the clusters.

```
install.packages("rpart")
library(rpart)
?rpart
# grow tree 
tree_mtcars <- rpart(mpg ~ ., method = "anova", data = mtcars)
tree_mtcars <- rpart(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)

tree_mtcars

summary(tree_mtcars) # detailed summary of splits

# Get R-squared
rsq.rpart(tree_mtcars)
?rsq.rpart

# plot tree 
plot(tree_mtcars, uniform = TRUE, main = "Regression Tree for mpg ")
text(tree_mtcars, use.n = TRUE, all = TRUE, cex = .8)
text(tree_mtcars, use.n = TRUE, all = TRUE, cex = .8)
```

Note that the although very informative, a basic decision tree is often not great for prediction.  If prediction is desirable, other models should also be explored.

Comment: really great answer, thanks a lot!! This is very helpful and informative - learned a lot going through your example and was able to assign classes